# Run python script without terminal or any app open

Tags: python, background

I have a python app that sends a notification whenever a specified YouTube channel gains a subscriber. I would like to have this run in the background instead of in terminal. Is there a way to do this? Here are my libaries if they could cause an issue:

```
import os
import urllib.request
import json
import time
from sys import platform
from plyer import notification
import subprocess
```

Comment: What is your OS?

Answer (score 0):

You can run your Python app as a service.

If you are using Windows you need some libraries such as:

- win32serviceutil
- win32service
- win32event
- servicemanager

Answer (score 0):

In case of your Operating System is Windows, you can use `.pyw` file extension and then run the app, it will run in the background, you could only stop it using the Task Manager.
On Linux, the easiest solution is to add `&` at the end of the command.
I. e: `python3 file.py &`.
But it will not be started every time you start up the computer, you can use tools such as systemd for example, to automatically run it every time.